# can I run Hadoop onflow (run map reduce when application is running)

Tags: java, hadoop

Can we generate output using hadoop on flow? I have big file which consist of logs and having appointment id's. If I use traditional RDBMS I can get appointment id's but it take 1 or 2 hrs.

Log file size is **800 GB**

On flow means show this appointment id when admin logs into system. 
can I run Hadoop onflow (run map reduce when application is running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is used for batch oriented processing of the data and not for real time or for adhoc analysis. For real time analysis of the data there are frameworks like S4, Twitter Storm, LinkedIn Samza and others. And for ad hoc queries there are frameworks like Drill, Imapala and others.

Looks like the requirement is more close to ad hoc querying and Hadoop as-is doesn't meet the requirements.

Comment: it means I can't use hadoop on flow. It's like client pass large file to Name Node and it will process further and give output right.

Comment: it is called batch processing - the file is not sent to the NN, look the the hadoop architecture for more details.